# Is it DataSet/DataTableAdapter can be considered as DAL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, 3-tier

I am doing a system with 3 tier architecture. I have 2 folder named DAL and BLL. Can I put my Dataset.xsd file in DAL folder and consider it as a that data access layer. Or is it wrong according to real world situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DAL is anything dealing directly with the data storage and retrieval. In your case, the `DataTableAdapter` is dealing directly with the data layer and thus is considered DAL - you are correct.
BLL will be any business rules or additional functionality that you wish to abstract above the DAL.

Comment: If I created a A.cs file in MS visual asp net to deal with this DataTableAdapter(Dataset.xsd ) and pass it to another B.cs(which is BLL).. What do I consider this A.cs as? DAL or BLL? Since I need show the codings for my project, I need to do this A.cs file as DAL since I can't show Dataset.xsd codings for my FYP presentation..

Comment: It's ok for BLL to know about DAL (A.cs),but the presentation layer generally only has knowledge of the BLL (B.cs). Ideally - the presentation layer (C.cs) should not know about A.cs.